# Induced representation is isotypical?

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, representation-theory

Is there a theorem like this for the induced representation?

> Let $N$ be a normal subgroup of a finite group $G$ and $\rho$ be an irreducible linear representation over any field $k$. Then one of the following must hold:

- There is a proper subgroup $H$ of $G$ containing $N$ such that $\rho$ is induced from an irreducible representation of H.
- $\operatorname{Res}_N(\rho)$ is isotypical

Comment: Yes, this is called the "isotypical-or-induced lemma." See https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Isotypical-or-induced_lemma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. See [Cor 6.12 in Isaacs's Character Theory](http://books.google.com/books?id=U-HmNAOdnkkC&pg=PA83). H is the inertia subgroup of an irreducible component of the restriction of rho to N. If H=G, then the restriction is homogenous.

Comment: Actually this reference is stated in terms of ordinary characters, but is easily translated since all of the modules involved are semi-simple over any field. The general field version is stated for instance on page 38 of Dixon–Puttaswamaiah's Modular Reps of Finite Groups.

Comment: I am sorry for interfering. I tried to understand the arguments in Dixons book, but I don't see how it helps to decide if $Ind^G_N(\rho)$ is isotypic. I just found, that $Res_N(\pi)$ is isotypic if the inertia subgroup is the whole group $G$. I hope you could give me a hint please

Comment: @user61052: perhaps you are working in a different situation. Here rho is defined on G, and we question its restriction to N. We only ask if rho is induced by some other character, we don't induce rho.